# Utilizar o método __get dentro do controller

Tags: php, symfony-2

Na minha entidade tenho o seguinte [método mágico](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return null;
}
```

No meu controlador tenho o seguinte código:

```
$clients = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository("AppBundle:Clients")
    ->findAll()
;

//...

$naoExiste = $app->getNaoexiste(),
```

Apesar do método `__get` existir dentro da entidade, o seguinte erro ocorre:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getNaoexiste" of class "AppBundle\Entity\Clients".

O método `__get` não funciona nas entidades?

Answer (score 0):

O método para chamar métodos que não existe não é o `__get`, é o `__call`.

`__get` é para chamar uma ação quando uma propriedade não existem.

`__call` é para chamar uma ação quando um método não existe.

Você também deve tomar um cuidado ao adicionar "funcionalidades mágicas", pois se o Doctrine, internamente verificar o método com `method_exists`, ele vai retornar `false`.

Comment: Obrigado Wallace, realmente troquei os métodos. Em relação ao Doctrine, em que situação a verificação do método com `method_exists` ocorre? Atualmente não tenho nenhuma propriedade com valores true/false, mas se houvesse poderia ser atribuído o valor `false` erroneamente, é isso que queres dizer?